# How to display Punjabi (Indian) font in Android devices?

Tags: android, html, fonts, webview

I have an application that I want to show Punjabi text. The text is in HTML file. I have custom font "Anmol.ttf" under css/style. The text appears fine in devices that are above 3.0 Android Version. However, in lower versions it has mistakes almost everywhere and plus in some phones it appears as boxes. Other apps with the same language is easily viewable, I am not sure how should I approach on fixing this. I have spent almost over 4 months finding the solution but have no luck. Please see the images below difference between the lower version text and the upper version text.

Below is "0.html" file that I am trying to upload.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/0.html");
    }
}
```

How it should look:
[image: This image is for upper version which looks fine.]

How it looks (needs to be fixed):
[image: This image is for lower version.]

Comment: Those symbols mean the font doesn't know how to interpret that letter.  Have you tried bundling the font with the app?

Comment: Bundling the font? I am not sure what you really mean. I have added a sample code for the app.

Comment: Is the ttf font in your res/fonts directory?  If not, try it that way so the font is used from your apk on all devices.

Comment: I have it in assets folder. I have seen everyone putting it in assets folder. That's not an issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add proper or pre formatted punjabi text in your html file.
If the punjabi text does not show in your html file then use Punjabi Font Converter

: http://www.sikhmarg.com/converter/

Here you can convert your punjabi font from one to another encoding

***e.g:*** if your font is Anmollipi the you can translate it to ***Unicode Correction***(Because Java supports Unicode encoding)

***Tip:***(first change to your font in which the text is typed then copy the text and again convert to Unicode)

after this paste the punjabi text to your html file and save it with encoding of ***utf 8***

[see the image, how to change encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Dm6.png)

Best of luck